# I need to encounter special symbols in MVC content and need to change colors

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net-mvc, mvcrazor

```
<td>@itme.content</td>//abcdefg*hijkl*mnopqr
```

hijkl<===Need to change to red.

Each special symbol position is not necessarily

How to deal with

Comment: You need to add more details to your question. So far, we only know your objective/task, not your problem.

Comment: Also how do you want to achieve this? Do you want to turn those to red when a button is clicked? Or when the page is first loaded?